# Compare data from reference sheet using VBA, give output if variation condition met

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on big data, I need to automate this process using VBA in excel
Any help using VBA would be appreciated

There are three sheets; reference, input and output

Reference Sheet values fixed

```
Jack (Position A2),  5(position B2);
Jones (Position A3) , 6(Position B3);
```

Input sheet[Input sheet values sequence may change, currently use vlookup for comparision]

```
Jones  (Position A2) , 11 (position B2);
Jack (Position A3)   , 4 (Position B3);
```

Output sheet(Output required if difference greater than 4 between reference and input
)

```
Jones (Position A2) , 11 (position B2);
```

Comment: You need to automate what process? I see no description of the process

Comment: did you try anything and got to a stand still? if so, post the code so we can help you find what went wrong, otherwise i would suggest you start by using a loop and the match function to extract a "success" row, and then copying it (when answering your condition of greater then 4)

Comment: @EngJon ...process to get output values, comparing input sheet with reference sheet

Comment: @AvishayCohen.. I am learning VBA,  if you have understood the problem,  pls share programming logic and function, i will learn function syntax from youtube.. thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, as i see it, you'll want to do the following steps-

first get how many rows you have in each sheet, you can do that with this snippet:

```
Worksheets.Select (1) 'this select the first sheet in a the current workbook
lastrow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row 'this return the row number of the last row that have a value <> empty in column A
```

do this for each of your sheets - to have an upper bound for your loops.

next is starting a loop, over your input sheet. you can now use the `Match` function to find if your item in input appear in the referance. and get it's value. then check the differance between them

if the diff is bigger then four, copy the whole line to output, otherwise increment your loop counter.

that should do it.

feel free to ask for clearafication, english is not my mother tounge so i might be a bit vague.